# Data recovery from a web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I have an API developed with asp.net core which allows to do CRUDs on DocumentType (types of a document) and next to I have asp.net core mvc web application from which I would like to recover the list of DocumentType, for communication between the two applications I use HttpClient. below is the code of the action which allows you to retrieve the list of documents:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<DocumentType> documentTypeliste = new List<DocumentType>();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44318/api/DocumentType"))
            {
                var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                documentTypeliste = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DocumentType>>(apiResponse);
            }
        }

        return View(documentTypeliste);
    }
```

However I am experiencing the error below which I still cannot resolve. Thank you for your help

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
> (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GEDRH.Models.Entities.DocumentType]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'success', line 1, position
> 11.

Comment: Inspect the json response that your web application returns. The error tells you that it does not have a list at the top level, so you cannot deserialize it into a `List<DocumentType>`.

Comment: Can you share your apiResponse?As `Pranav Hosangadi` said,it cannot be deserialized to a list.

Comment: i just shared my apiResponse

Answer (score 0):

I solved a probléme

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var documentTypeliste = new List<DocumentType>();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44318/api/DocumentType"))
            {
                var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var list = JObject.Parse(apiResponse)["data"].Select(el => new { Id = (int)el["id"], Name = (string)el["name"], Description = (string)el["description"] }).ToList();
                //var names = list.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                //var descriptions = list.Select(p => p.Description).ToList();
                //var ids = list.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
                foreach(var it in list)
                {
                   DocumentType dt = new DocumentType
                    {
                        Id = it.Id,
                        Name = it.Name,
                        Description = it.Description
                    };
                    documentTypeliste.Add(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        ViewBag.PersonTypeListe = _servicePersonType.SelectAll();
        return View(documentTypeliste);
    }
```